# highlight text within textbox programmatically / via GUI

Tags: .net, vb.net

How may i highlight the text when say, after a textbox is enabled after the click of a button? (programmatically or via the GUI) Missing out something very obvious here, thankx i appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
            With TextBox1
            If .Text.Trim <> "" Then
                .SelectionStart = 0
                .SelectionLength = .Text.Length
            End If
        End With
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

textBox1.selectall()